Generic Deserializer Failing in one case
I am making an http call and the response comes back as such (Redacted)
{
  "Theaters": [
    {
      "id": "259cf043-6195-42dd-bfdb-640969e0bfb9",
      "name": "Theater1",
      "slug": "Theater1",
      "shows": [
        {
          "id": "73436465-1f14-400f-bfbf-ab6766269e70",
          "name": "show1"
        },
        {
          "id": "9a268b42-4f13-4f7a-9c7d-d40a30d7a6eb",
          "name": "show2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "9c6a0933-e519-4d6e-b027-e6c47c60641b",
      "name": "Theater3",
      "slug": "Theater3",
      "parks": [
        {
          "id": "18608db3e-fa23-4284-89dd-9fcd0wes9c9c",
          "name": "show3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My C# classes are:
public class Theater
{
    public Theater()
    {
        shows = new List<ShowBase>();
    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string slug { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShowBase> shows { get; set; }

}

public class ShowBase
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}

public class TheaterList
{
    public TheaterList()
    {
        theaters= new List<Theater>();
    }
    public List<Theater> theaters;
}

I am using a generic function to get the results
public virtual async Task<T> Get<T>()
{
    response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
    Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));
}

It is failing for this payload comes back empty
I have called it in 2 ways
var result = await TheaterGetter.Get<TheaterList>();

and
var result = await TheaterGetter.Get<Theater>();

Both come back empty and shouldnt.
I also tried this but got an error saying IConvertible needed to be implemented.
var result = await TheaterGetter.GetList<List<Theater>, Theater>();

public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetList<T, B>()
{
    response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
    Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<B>(json);
    return (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));
}

Any help would be appreciated

Why are you using Convert.ChangeType? data should already be of type T in the first  method because Deserialize<T> returns a T...

Fair point, thank you.  Still leaves me with the main issue however

It would be nice to have a [mre]. What's client? If it's HttpClient, there's GetStringAsync that saves you the  headache of dealing with response. I'd also debug the code and look at what exactly you're getting back from the HTTP call.

yes client is HttpClient.  it works for all my other cases with different classes.

Well, I'm looking at that JSON, and I'm looking at the class declarations, and I'm not seeing a class that has a single property named Theaters. TheaterList comes close, but its constructor initializes a non-existent variable shows to a List<Theater>() and has a property named theaters which shares all the same characters but the first. I think this might just be a typo.

yes, typo, fixed

But the difference in case means that it may not be matching Theaters in the JSON with theaters in the C#.

public List<Theater> Theaters { get; set;} -- You can remove the empty Constructor(s) and the Lists' initializers, not needed -- If you need to keep the lower-case, decorate with [JsonPropertyName("Theaters")], or set the PropertyNameCaseInsensitive property of the JsonSerializerOptions

public List<Theater> theaters; -- this is a field not a property.  System.Text.Json does not deserialize fields by default.  Either convert to a property, or enable serialization of public fields by setting JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields as shown in How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?.

And as noted by @Jimi System.Text.Json is case sensitive so you must enable case-insensitive serialization as shown in JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails or apply [JsonPropertyName("Theaters")] as shown in What is the equivalent of Newtonsoft.Json's JsonProperty attribute in System.Text.Json?.

However, even with those fixes the (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T)); will likely fail.  What are you trying to do there?  Are you thinking that TheaterList should be automatically convertible to List<Theater>?

You have a few problems here:

public List<Theater> theaters; is a field not a property, but System.Text.Json does not serialize fields by default.  You need to either set JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields to true or change the field to a property.

System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default, but the field name theaters does not match the JSON property name "Theaters".  You need to make them consistent or use one of the alternatives from JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails or What is the equivalent of Newtonsoft.Json's JsonProperty attribute in System.Text.Json?.

Your root JSON object corresponds to TheaterList so you need use that type for your Get<T>() method.

You are getting the response as a string, then manually deserializing the string.  While this will work, it will not be as efficient as calling HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync() which deserializes asynchronously from the response stream without the intermediate string representation.

It's not clear you need this, but your Theater type does not have a property corresponding to the JSON property "parks"

In the first version of your Get<T>() method, you call
(T)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));

This is not necessary as data is already of type T.
In your second version, you call:
(List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));

This will not work.  It seems you are trying to return the value of TheaterList.Theaters in some generic manner, but C# does not have a built-in architecture to generically convert from one type to another, as Convert.ChangeType() is mainly used to convert from or to primitive types like string or int.


To fix #1-#5, modify your C# classes as follows:
public class TheaterList
{
    public List<Theater> Theaters { get; set; } = new(); // FIXED - made a property and capitalized the first letter
}

public class Theater
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShowBase> shows { get; set; } = new List<ShowBase>();
    public ICollection<ShowBase> parks { get; set; } = new List<ShowBase>(); // TODO: include only if required
}

public class ShowBase
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

And your TheaterGetter.Get<TValue>() method as follows:
public virtual async Task<TValue?> Get<TValue>(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
    await client.GetFromJsonAsync<TValue?>(URL, cancellationToken : cancellationToken);

Then call it as follows:
var result = (await TheaterGetter.Get<TheaterList>())
    ?.Theaters;

Demo #1 here.
Now, if you also require a fix for #6 -- an automatic and generic way to convert from TheaterList to List<Theater> -- then there is nothing built in so you will need to do it yourself.  One possibility would be to create a generic interface and extension method like the following:
public interface IConvertibleTo<out TToType>
{
    TToType ConvertTo();
}

public static class ConvertibleExtensions
{
    public static TToType? ConvertTo<TToType>(this IConvertibleTo<TToType>? from) => from is null ? default(TToType?) : from.ConvertTo();
}

Then make TheaterList implement the interface:
public class TheaterList : IConvertibleTo<List<Theater>>
{
    List<Theater> IConvertibleTo<List<Theater>>.ConvertTo() => Theaters;

    public List<Theater> Theaters { get; set; } = new();
}

And finally you will be able to add a TheaterGetter.Get<TDto, TValue> method that automatically deserializes a theater list and converts it to a list of theaters as follows:
public virtual async Task<TValue?> Get<TDto, TValue>(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
    where TDto : IConvertibleTo<TValue> =>
    (await Get<TDto?>(cancellationToken)).ConvertTo<TValue>();

And call it like so:
var result = await TheaterGetter.Get<TheaterList, List<Theater>>();

Demo #2 here.
